# Bought a new Dell laptop which appears to be a used one?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I bought a Dell laptop on 29 jan 2018, while I was using it for the first day I opened the C drive and saw that there is a tmp named folder which was modified on 26 jan 2018 meaning before date of purchased but how is that possible if the laptop is opened on 29 jan for the first ever time. Also, there are many Windows logs from Windows event viewer which show 26 jan 2018 (more than 100 logs) so I just need to know if the laptop was opened before I purchased it because I found some scratches as well on the sides and front of the laptop. Below are the links of the folder and logs images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This sounds more like the laptop was started after the windows image was installed.

Comment: means the laptop was opened and booted before i purchased it, right?

Comment: This can be, yes. But I don't see a problem with that as this is to be expected. The laptop **should** be tested at least once before delivery.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the logs you found indicate prolonged  system usage, program installation, or actual signs of activity this is *probably* normal.

If it appears to have been turned on for a brief period, had one of your suppliers programs installed and then turned off then it is probably as new as it can be.

Just because you bought it "new" does not mean that the image used to create the operating system was created at the date of manufacture.

Many companies such as Dell like to bundle their own programs into a system. This means that they have to install the operating system onto a "clean" system, install their tools and then create a system image that they can then apply to other computers.

Any time they wish to update that image then they either start from scratch again or they update that system image with newer tools.

I've seen several computers that show this kind of behaviour in the logs, that the system was "up" for an hour or so several times for a period of 6-8 months prior to manufacture of the actual machine. This does not mean that your machine was bought "used" unless you can see logs indicating that the system was actually running for several days.

Most system manufacturers will also run a test suite on the hardware after installing the system image in order to prove the hardware is not faulty prior to delivery. This could well show in the logs up to a week before shipping.

If you are concerned that you have been sent a refurbished (used but returned) machine then you should contact your supplier.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kQEZqn
https://ibb.co/iDJuqn   but there are like more than 100 logs which shows that certain softwares like dell support and dell digital apps were updated and also there are a lot of scratches on the laptop and near usb ports and no side plastic coating because the same model when i saw at the other store was having side plastic coating. the thing is that the dealer is not ready accept anything and he is just telling me go anywhere you want to go and do what ever you want to do,also the dell customer care tells there is no damage so its ok but a used laptop for a price of new

Comment: also the warranty on the dell site for this laptop is showing only for 11 months which should be atleast a year. and there are many logs i have posted two more links for the images of the logs but the box after manufacturing is opened at the time of selling to the customer untill then the laptop is not opened right ? please clarify this doubt

Comment: It is difficult to say for certain what the provenance of the laptop is. It could be that someone opened the box to have a look at it and did some damage when they did so. If you bought from a third party shop then it is difficult to know what they did to it and as a customer you should have the right to return it if you are unhappy.